jenkins devops in kubernates fails beacuse of org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: dfb66fca-365a-4a1f-ad39-a1aa21f15e1a
my devops break down all the time. besides, i cannot see the pod logs in kubernates, because they always die in a few seconds. I look at jenkins Console Output, get the result:
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/yaohaihan/k8s-cicd-demo.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: kubernates devops-test/github-k8s-cicd-demo-19-n1pjj-0x5r6-lcm44
devops-test/github-k8s-cicd-demo-19-n1pjj-0x5r6-lcm44 Container jnlp was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
devops-test/github-k8s-cicd-demo-19-n1pjj-0x5r6-lcm44 Container my-agent was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)

- jnlp -- terminated (0)
-----Logs-------------
 -noreconnect                          : If the connection ends, don't retry
                                         and just exit. (default: false)
 -protocols VAL                        : Specify the remoting protocols to
                                         attempt when instanceIdentity is
                                         provided.
 -proxyCredentials USER:PASSWORD       : HTTP BASIC AUTH header to pass in for
                                         making HTTP authenticated proxy
                                         requests.
 -tunnel HOST:PORT                     : Connect to the specified host and
                                         port, instead of connecting directly
                                         to Jenkins. Useful when connection to
                                         Jenkins needs to be tunneled. Can be
                                         also HOST: or :PORT, in which case the
                                         missing portion will be auto-configured
                                         like the default behavior
 -url URL                              : Specify the Jenkins root URLs to
                                         connect to.
 -version                              : Shows the version of the remoting jar
                                         and then exits (default: false)
 -webSocket                            : Make a WebSocket connection to Jenkins
                                         rather than using the TCP port.
                                         (default: false)
 -webSocketHeader NAME=VALUE           : Additional WebSocket header to set, eg
                                         for authenticating with reverse
                                         proxies. To specify multiple headers,
                                         call this flag multiple times, one
                                         with each header
 -workDir FILE                         : Declares the working directory of the
                                         remoting instance (stores cache and
                                         logs by default)


- my-agent -- terminated (0)
-----Logs-------------
 -noreconnect                          : If the connection ends, don't retry
                                         and just exit. (default: false)
 -protocols VAL                        : Specify the remoting protocols to
                                         attempt when instanceIdentity is
                                         provided.
 -proxyCredentials USER:PASSWORD       : HTTP BASIC AUTH header to pass in for
                                         making HTTP authenticated proxy
                                         requests.
 -tunnel HOST:PORT                     : Connect to the specified host and
                                         port, instead of connecting directly
                                         to Jenkins. Useful when connection to
                                         Jenkins needs to be tunneled. Can be
                                         also HOST: or :PORT, in which case the
                                         missing portion will be auto-configured
                                         like the default behavior
 -url URL                              : Specify the Jenkins root URLs to
                                         connect to.
 -version                              : Shows the version of the remoting jar
                                         and then exits (default: false)
 -webSocket                            : Make a WebSocket connection to Jenkins
                                         rather than using the TCP port.
                                         (default: false)
 -webSocketHeader NAME=VALUE           : Additional WebSocket header to set, eg
                                         for authenticating with reverse
                                         proxies. To specify multiple headers,
                                         call this flag multiple times, one
                                         with each header
 -workDir FILE                         : Declares the working directory of the
                                         remoting instance (stores cache and
                                         logs by default)

[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Queue task was cancelled
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: dfb66fca-365a-4a1f-ad39-a1aa21f15e1a
Finished: ABORTED

next it's part of my pipeline. i dont need to show all of them, the script ended before it actually executed.
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
                    yaml """
                    apiVersion: v1
                    kind: Pod
                    spec:
                      containers:
                      - name: my-agent
                        image: 192.168.110.122:8858/library/agent-maven:latest
                        imagePullPolicy: Always
                      - name: jnlp
                        image: jenkins/inbound-agent:4.10-3
                        args: ['\$(JENKINS_SECRET)', '\$(JENKINS_NAME)']
                        env:
                        - name: JENKINS_SECRET
                          valueFrom:
                            fieldRef:
                              fieldPath: metadata.annotations['jenkins.io/secret']
                        - name: JENKINS_NAME
                          valueFrom:
                            fieldRef:
                              fieldPath: metadata.annotations['jenkins.io/name']
                        - name: JENKINS_URL
                          value: "http://jenkins-service.devops-test.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
                    """
                    defaultContainer 'my-agent'

                }

    }

    parameters {
        gitParameter name: 'BRANCH_NAME', branch: '', branchFilter: '.*', defaultValue: 'master', description: '请选择要发布的分支', quickFilterEnabled: false, selectedValue: 'NONE', tagFilter: '*', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
        choice(name: 'NAMESPACE', choices: ['devops-dev', 'devops-test', 'devops-prod'], description: '命名空间')
        string(name: 'TAG_NAME', defaultValue: 'snapshot', description: '标签名称，必须以 v 开头，例如：v1、v1.0.0')
    }

    environment {
        DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'harbor-user-pass'
        GIT_REPO_URL = 'https://github.com/yaohaihan/k8s-cicd-demo.git'
        GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'github-user-pass'
        GIT_ACCOUNT = 'root' // change me
        KUBECONFIG_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'ec9a10b4-fa75-44bd-8832-0a5f1596479f'   cat ~/.kube/config，
        REGISTRY = '192.168.110.122:8858'
        DOCKERHUB_NAMESPACE = 'wolfcode' // change me
        APP_NAME = 'k8s-cicd-demo'
        SONAR_SERVER_URL = 'http://192.168.113.120:32276'
        SONAR_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'sonarqube-token'
    }





    stages {

        stage('unit test') {
            steps {

                sh 'mvn clean test'

            }
        }


i would like to figure out why it happens and how can i solve it.

This line in your log seems to indicate that your container didn't have a long running process in it and completed as soon as it was started
Container my-agent was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)

You can supply your own command to override whatever is the image default. Look at this Kubernetes plugin documentation

command The command the container will execute. Will overwrite the Docker entrypoint. A typical value is sleep.


args The arguments passed to the command. A typical value is 99999999.


thank you, i have give my container this command     command:
- cat
tty: true
so that they can keep alive and active. if i dont give any command, they will die once they are created
